# Swift - TableView, change font of even rows to bold

Tags: swift, tableview, tablecell

I have a tableview and i want to change the font of even rows, Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "ProductListTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductListTableViewCell

    let product = productList[indexPath.row]

    cell.productName.text = product.name
    cell.productPrice.text = "\(product.price) manat"

    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.productName.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(13.0)
        cell.productPrice.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(13.0)
    }
    return cell
}
```

when i run my code, at the beginning everything works correctly, when i scroll my table view, all new rows appeared on screen becomes bold, both even and old rows. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that a table view **reuses** cells. That's why you get them from a method named `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)`.

You set the font to bold when it's an even-numbered row, but you don't set it back to normal when it's an odd-numbered row. If the cell was previously used for an even-numbered row, and is now being used for an odd-numbered row, it still has a bold font.

```
let weight = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) ? UIFontWeightBold : UIFontWeightRegular
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13, weight: weight)
cell.productName.font = font
cell.productPrice.font = font
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it worked. I had to set the odd rows too

Answer (score 1):

Your reusable cells are all being set to bold. Add an else to the if row % 2 == 0 to set the cell back to normal font when it is used in an odd row.

Comment: thanks for reply, as you said i had to set normal font for odd rows too